# Find date and price difference between duplicate columns in a data frame. Append information to rows in data frame

Tags: python, dataframe, duplicates, analysis

Need to find **date difference** and **price difference** between duplicate columns (by name) for entire Data Frame which is much larger than 7 rows.
If the duplicates can all be added to the **same row** that would be preferable as seen in example below.

Sample Code:

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'CarMake':['Toyota', 'Ford', 'Nissan', 'Hyundai','Toyota', 'Ford', 'Nissan', 'Hyundai'],
        'DateSold':['1-2-18','1-2-18','1-3-18','1-3-18','1-2-20','1-2-20','1-3-20','1-3-20'],
        'Price':['20000','21000','22000','23000','15000','16000','17000','18000']}         
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['Price']=df['Price'].astype(str).astype(float)
df['DateSold']=pd.to_datetime(df['DateSold'])
```

To see data types:

```
df.dtypes
```

Expected Output:

```
   CarMake   DateSold    Price
0   Toyota 2018-01-02  20000.0
1     Ford 2018-01-02  21000.0
2   Nissan 2018-01-03  22000.0
3  Hyundai 2018-01-03  23000.0
4   Toyota 2020-01-02  15000.0
5     Ford 2020-01-02  16000.0
6   Nissan 2020-01-03  17000.0
7  Hyundai 2020-01-03  18000.0
```

Desired Output:
It would be preferable to have the date in [months].

```
   CarMake DateSold DateSold2  Price Price2 PriceDifference DateDifference
0   Toyota   1-2-18    1-2-20  20000  15000           -5000             24
1     Ford   1-2-18    1-2-20  21000  16000           -5000             24
2   Nissan   1-3-18    1-3-20  22000  17000           -5000             24
3  Hyundai   1-3-18    1-3-20  23000  18000           -5000             24
```

Comment: You say you want the difference between duplicate columns, but the example appears to be merging rows with duplicate CarMake fields. Are you concerned with columns or rows?  What happens if you have 3 cars with the same make? Will they merge to one row somehow, or will there be 3 rows, one for each combination?

Comment: Great question. I would like all the duplicate information of a single make type to be added to the original makes row. Having one for each combination would be great because I don't want to lose valuable information.

Comment: You could sort them by CarMake. Then iterate through them with two pointers. The first points to the first row, the second points to the next row. If they have the same CarMake, compare them and make a new row in a new table, then move the second pointer forward one and repeat. If they differ, move the first pointer forward one row and set the second pointer to just after the first. Repeating like this will compare all combinations. You may also want to find a way to keep rows that don't have duplicates.

Comment: Could you provide some example code that works with the example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to compare every row with every other row that has the same `CarMake` value, then add the comparisons to a new table. The most efficient way to do this is to first sort the list by `CarMake` and then iterate over all the rows. Once the `CarMake` field in the next row doesn't match the `CarMake` field in the current row, you know you have found all cars of that make and can change which row you are comparing to. This is much faster than comparing to all rows.

Here is an example that does just this, as well as checking for singletons and entering them in the new table with no comparison data.

```py
# set up example: added a singleton and triple-duplicate example and varied dates more
import pandas as pd
data = {'CarMake':['Toyota', 'Ford', 'Nissan', 'Hyundai','Toyota', 'Ford', 'Nissan', 'Toyota'],
        'DateSold':['1-2-18','1-2-18','5-3-17','1-3-18','1-2-20','1-2-20','1-3-20','6-3-20'],
        'Price':['20000','21000','22000','23000','15000','16000','17000','18000']}         
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['Price']=df['Price'].astype(str).astype(float)
df['DateSold']=pd.to_datetime(df['DateSold'])

# sort our data
df.sort_values('CarMake', inplace=True)
# make list for building the new table
new_data = []

# loop through all rows once
for one in range(len(df)):
    one_row = df.iloc[one]
    one_make = one_row['CarMake']

    # check for singleton (non-duplicate row)
    # if the previous make or next make match, there is a duplicate,
    # otherwise it is a singleton
    prev_make = df.iloc[one - 1]['CarMake'] if one > 0 else None
    next_make = df.iloc[one + 1]['CarMake'] if one < len(df) - 1 else None
    if one_make != prev_make and one_make != next_make:
        # found a singleton
        new_data.append({
            'CarMake': one_make,
            'DateSold': one_row['DateSold'],
            'DateSold2': None,
            'Price': one_row['Price'],
            'Price2': None,
            'PriceDifference': None,
            'DateDifference': None,
        })
        continue
    
    # there is at least one duplicate, find them all
    for two in range(one + 1, len(df)):
        two_row = df.iloc[two]
        two_make = two_row['CarMake']

        if one_make == two_make:
            # found a duplicate
            new_data.append({
                'CarMake': one_make,
                'DateSold': one_row['DateSold'],
                'DateSold2': two_row['DateSold'],
                'Price': one_row['Price'],
                'Price2': two_row['Price'],
                'PriceDifference': abs(one_row['Price'] - two_row['Price']),
                'DateDifference': abs(
                    (one_row['DateSold'].year  - two_row['DateSold'].year) * 12 + 
                    (one_row['DateSold'].month - two_row['DateSold'].month)
                ),
            })
        else:
            break # no more matches, move `one` forward

new_df = pd.DataFrame(new_data)
print(new_df)
```

Output:

```
   CarMake   DateSold  DateSold2    Price   Price2  PriceDifference  DateDifference
0     Ford 2018-01-02 2020-01-02  21000.0  16000.0           5000.0            24.0
1  Hyundai 2018-01-03        NaT  23000.0      NaN              NaN             NaN
2   Nissan 2017-05-03 2020-01-03  22000.0  17000.0           5000.0            32.0
3   Toyota 2018-01-02 2020-01-02  20000.0  15000.0           5000.0            24.0
4   Toyota 2018-01-02 2020-06-03  20000.0  18000.0           2000.0            29.0
5   Toyota 2020-01-02 2020-06-03  15000.0  18000.0           3000.0             5.0
```

Comment: I appreciate the ram friendly answer! Very elegant solution, especially with the changes in data. What if you had an extra column in the original data frame (df) that was named "Model" as Camry or something. How would you add that information to their respective rows? Would you do it by referencing df while appending new_data?

Comment: Sometimes a "DateSold" is a later date than "DateSold2" of the same resulting column. This causes negatives without the abs(). I was wondering if there was any way to check and correct this making sure that earlier dates in time are always assigned to the "DateSold" column.

Comment: When appending to `new_data`, you can see that I simply made a dictionary object where the keys are the column names and the values are the values for that row. Pandas does the rest. So, do add another column, you could simply add another entry in the dictionary (`'Model': one_row['Model']`). When calling `df.sort_values()`, the first item can be a list of strings, where each string is a column name. It will sort the items in order of those columns. Thus, you could simply sort by `DateSold` second, and the oldest date will then always be in `DateSold`.

Comment: @Tevin Avery what if I wanted to track the price of a single make and model over time? Assuming there are three or more sales I'd like to see how its sell price changes over time. So for this one, instead of creating a new row for each comparison I want to accumulate all of the sale dates and prices in one place for each make/model so that I can then plot its change over time. I can add another question if you would like to get the answer for it. Just let me know.

Comment: You should use the original table. Just use pandas to get all rows with the make and model (I think you could use the [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) function), then use `matplotlib` to show the points on a graph, with dates on one axis and sale prices on the other.